# Office.context.mailbox.item.dateTimeCreated is giving undefined

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to use Office.context.mailbox.item.dateTimeCreated and used 1.1 office.js version but it is giving me undefined

I tried changing version in CLI to 1 and 1.3 but it's giving the same.

This is my javascript script tag

Comment: Is it a newly created item? Did you try to call the `Save` method prior?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [saveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-preview&preserve-view=true#outlook-office-messagecompose-saveasync-member(1)) method which asynchronously saves an item. When invoked, this method saves the current message as a draft and returns the item ID via the callback function. In Outlook on the web or Outlook in online mode, the item is saved to the server. In Outlook in cached mode, the item is saved to the local cache. Some properties can be changed after calling the `saveAsync` method.

Comment: So what should I do after calling saveAsync function?

Comment: After saving the item you may try to get a property value anew.

Answer (score 0):

Office.context.mailbox.item.dataTimeCreated only supports Message Read and Appointment Read. If you are using it on Message Compose, it will return undefined.